# Why the android app does not work on real device?

Tags: android, vb.net, sockets

I have an application that sends message to a socket server, when I'm using the emulator works, but when I go to my smartphone, the application does not send.

---

```
The server is created by VB.NET. A simple console that receives messages.
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net

Public Module MainModule

    Dim server As New TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.100"), 11000)
    Dim client As New TcpClient
    Dim stream As NetworkStream

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim str As String
        server.Start()
        client = server.AcceptTcpClient
        stream = client.GetStream()
        Dim r_byt(client.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
        stream.Read(r_byt, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize)
        str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(r_byt)
        Console.WriteLine(str)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Responce_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim s_byt() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Got it" & vbCr)
        stream.Write(s_byt, 0, s_byt.Length)
        stream.Flush()
        stream.Close()
        client.Close()
        server.Stop()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Now I will show the Android code that sends messages to the server.

```
package com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Client extends Activity {
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.0.100";
    private static final int SERVER_PORT = 11000;
    private Socket socket;

    private EditText InputText = null;
    private Button ButtonSend = null;
    private TextView LabelReceived = null;
    private Thread thread = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      

        InputText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.InputText);
        ButtonSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonSend);
        LabelReceived = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.LabelReceived);
        thread = new Thread(new ClientThread());

        if (thread != null) {
            thread.start();
        }

        ButtonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try {
                    if (socket != null) {
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

                        out.println(InputText.getText().toString());
                        out.flush();

                        out.close();
                    } else {
                        LabelReceived.setText("socket is null!");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LabelReceived.setText(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress IAddress = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(IAddress, SERVER_PORT);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                socket = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use a label to display errors too, and when I press the button to send appears "socket is null".

These codes worked today before I go to school, but when I arrived I tried to do it again and no longer worked. So I believe it is a simple problem but it is very hidden.

Comment: Assumption : Your emulator can access the local intranet for socket server while if your real device is on 3G ( not in Wifi ) then it will surely not work.

Comment: Trying to connect to the bad ip address is my guess. You need to show some code, so we can help you

Comment: My device is in WI-FI. My code works today in the morning.

Comment: I set INTERNET permission.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take out your request to server in AsyncTask or Services

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
@Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
       something
 }
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      something
}
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
      something
}
```

and call this like

```
MyTask mt = new MyTask();           
mt.execute();
```

Comment: I'll edit my question and I'll post the code I'm using.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was much different than I was expecting that. It was simply my antivirus that was blocking the connection, I added an exception and now the socket is working.